# Bokeh - matplotlib - histogram - blank plot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, bokeh, jupyter-notebook

I have the following code that runs in a **jupyter notebook** with **python 3**:

```
from bokeh import mpl
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

output_notebook()

plt.hist([1,2,3,3,3,3,4,5,4])

show(mpl.to_bokeh())
```

This plots me a blank plot with no draws in it.
[image: jupyter console]
**Is a bug or I am doing something wrong?**

Comment: Is there any output in the browser console?

Comment: HI ! , I have added an image

Comment: I should have been more clear. If you can share the output of your browser console (in Chrome it's Settings -> More Tools -> Developer Tools), that'd be helpful in diagnosing.

Comment: This is no longer possible. Since Bokeh 12.5 (April 2017), [support for Matplotlib has been deprecated](https://bokeh.github.io/blog/2017/4/5/release-0-12-5/), and `mpl.to_bokeh()` has been removed. Also see [this Github comment](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/6249#issuecomment-299981362) by bryevdv.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that plt.hist is behaving somewhat like plt.plot and plt.show.  If you call plt.show() before show(mpl.to_bokeh()) you will get the same result for an example system as you can see here:
[image]

I am not sure of the root cause of this behavior but a workaround is to simply create the histogram using bokeh. This is not hard if you follow the bokeh example:

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/histogram.html

For the example in your question you can do the following:

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook, vplot

output_notebook()
hist, edges = np.histogram([1,2,3,3,3,3,4,5,4])

p1 = figure(title="Bokeh Hist",background_fill_color="#E8DDCB")

p1.quad(top=hist, bottom=0, left=edges[:-1], right=edges[1:],
        fill_color="#036564", line_color="#033649")
show(p1)
```

Giving:

[image]